# 15 feet FireWire cable does not work

Tags: hard-drive, firewire

in an attempt to move all my noisy drives to nearby closet and reduce noise at my desk, I just purchased a 15 feet FireWire 800 cable ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0069VBAXU?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0069VBAXU))
I read online that FireWire was good until 4.5m (15 feet) but my drives do not mount any longer.
Am I to assume the cable is broken/DOA or is this an issue of length?
Needless to say my drives mount fine with my shorter 6 feet FireWire 800 cables

Answer (score 1):

It could be either, but if you look at the customer reviews you will see a number of people have had problems with this cable due to the length.

At a guess, the cable is not a "top quality" cable and your system may even be very slightly out of spec (maybe voltage?) as well, so the cable is not working.

Its possible a higher quality cable will work.

If you want to check if the cable is broken/doa, you can always get a multimeter out and test each set of pins.

Comment: Could you recommend a good brand of cable that would work with longer distances? As for my specs I'm using a Mac Book Pro from 2 years ago with a thunderbolt to FireWire 800 adapter

Comment: Sorry, no.  Being an armchair critic is easy.  Actually finding solutions is hard.  (but seriously, its unfortunately probably a matter of "suck it and see").   http://www.amazon.com/9PIN-BETA-FireWire-Cable-Clear/product-reviews/B00404CCCQ/ref=cm_cr_pr_hist_4?ie=UTF8&filterBy=addThreeStar&showViewpoints=0&filterByStar=four_star&pageNumber=1 seems to have good reviews, so I might be inclined to take a punt on it - but I know no more about it then you do.